# How to archive files with 7z from current directory into a specific directory in the resulting archive?

Tags: 7-zip

In the current directory I have a file named "file.txt".

How to create an archive with this file in a directory "dir", so when the archive is unpacked the "dir" directory will be created with the "file.txt" in it?

Preferable it should be through a command line option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not pointing to your specific directory with the drop-down options, you might want to look into self-extracting archive executables. There are a lot of great answers and walkthroughs [already here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/283698/create-7-zip-sfx-executable). You can just add instructions or a script to your 7-zip file and have it accomplish any number of different things when running and extracting.

Comment: Thank, I will take a look at the reference.